# Can I later change sorting criteria of a map in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, compare

Suppose I have a map, key as char and value as integer. Based on the property of black-red tree, every time I insert a new pair, the map will be sorted by char. After all insertion, I want to sort my map again by its value(i.e. the integer number). My question is, can I do this by my own compare function? Here is the code:

```
sort(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), MyComp);

class MyComp
{
public:
    bool operator()(const pair<char, int>& x, const pair<char, int>& y) const
    {
        return x.second > y.second;
    }
};
```

My code can not compile, but I do not know why I can't do this. Can anyone help me?

And further more, if this is not a good way to solve the problem, is there any other way to do this?

I can think of a way that is to create another map and insert again by exchange the value and key, it works but waste much more space. Thanks!

Comment: You can't change the sorting criteria of a map *after* it has been instantiated, but you can construct it with your own sorting functor.

Comment: I do not want change its sorting criteria, I just want to add another my own sorting and apply to it one more time.

Comment: You can't sort the map after it has been instantiated. The map sorts itself on each insertion.

Comment: You'd have to re-sort every element, might as well move them to a new map with the correct sort order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rearrange the elements of a `std::map<K, V>`: the value type of this map is actually `std::pair<K const, V>` and, thus, the elements are not Swappable as is required for `std::sort()`.

You can, however, change the sorting criteria by customizing the predicate of the `std::map<...>` itself:

```
std::map<K, V, Compare> m;
```

Note, however, that the comparison function in `Compare` takes two `K const&` as argument, rather than a `std::pair<K const, V>`.

BTW, if you ever get an element from a `std::map<K, V, ...>`, the value type is **not** `std::pair<K, V>` but `std::pair<K const, V>`. However, often the latter type implicitly converts into the former, i.e., you can call

```
void f(std::pair<char, int> const&) { ... }
```

with a `std::pair<char const, int>`:

```
f(std::pair<char const, int>('a', 1));
```

This operation will, however, **not** just provide a reference to the original object but construct a new object. In the setup using `char` and `int` this isn't much of a problem but the conversion can be rather expensive, e.g., if one of the members is a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting criteria for `std::map` is set only once upon creation and you cannot change it later neither you can rearrange existing data inside your map. So if you need to resort your data differently you can use different container like `boost::multi_index` that supports multiple cafeterias for sorting or copy data to another container and sort it.